# Chain memoizer in python

Tags: python, memoization

I already have a memoizer that works quite well. It uses the pickle dumps to serializes the inputs and creates MD5 hash as a key. The function results are quite large and are stored as pickle files with file name being MD5 hash.  When I call two memoized function one after another, the `memoizer` will load the output of the first function and pass it to the second function.  The second function will serialize it, create MD5 and then load the output.  Here is a very simple code:

```
@memoize
def f(x):
    ...
    return y

@memoize
def g(x):
    ...
    return y

y1 = f(x1)
y2 = g(y1)
```

`y1` is loaded from the disk when `f` is evaluated and then it's serialized when `g` is evaluated. Is it possible to somehow bypass this step and pass the key of `y1` (i.e. MD5 hash) to `g`? If `g` already has this key, it loads the `y2` from the disk.  If it doesn't, it "requests" the full `y1` for the evaluation of `g`.

**EDIT:**

```
import cPickle as pickle
import inspect
import hashlib

class memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arg = inspect.getargspec(self.func).args
        file_name = self._get_key(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            f = open(file_name, "r")
            out = pickle.load(f)
            f.close()
        except:
            out = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
            f = open(file_name, "wb")
            pickle.dump(out, f, 2)
            f.close()

        return out

    def _arg_hash(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _str = pickle.dumps(args, 2) + pickle.dumps(kwargs, 2)
        return hashlib.md5(_str).hexdigest()

    def _src_hash(self):
        _src = inspect.getsource(self.func)
        return hashlib.md5(_src).hexdigest()

    def _get_key(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arg = self._arg_hash(*args, **kwargs)
        src = self._src_hash()
        return src + '_' + arg + '.pkl'
```

Comment: Why don't you just use one namespace for both of your functions? I mean you should use one key-value based file (like json or etc. ) for both.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the current approach? Is it that (almost) the same big blob of data is saved twice on disc? If one of the two functions is only doing "cheap" stuff, don't `@memoize` it; otherwise, I don't think there's a good way around this.

Comment: @MSeifert this is a very simplified example, I have the whole sets of functions that use output of one as an input to another.  So it's not always easy to convert it to `g(f(x))`.

Comment: function evaluation is very expensive, loading from disk as serialization is cheaper.  However, the datasets are quite large, so if I can avoid unnecessary I/O and serialization, it would speed up my code even further.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of `memoize`? From what I understand, you always hash the arguments, and always read the result from the disk? Couldn't you just cache the result in memory?

Comment: @VincentSavard: ^ I suppose it's done by OS's filesystem cache already. Is it recalculating the hash what's slow?

Comment: @mss: Did you profile your code? Where does the actual slowdown happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do it in an automatic fashion but I generally think it's better to be explicit about "lazy" evaluation. So I'll present a way that adds an additional argument to your memoized functions: `lazy`. But instead of files, pickle and md5 I'll simplify the helpers a bit:

```
# I use a dictionary as storage instead of files
storage = {}

# No md5, just hash
def calculate_md5(obj):
    print('calculating md5 of', obj)
    return hash(obj)

# create dictionary entry instead of pickling the data to a file
def create_file(md5, data):
    print('creating file for md5', md5)
    storage[md5] = data

# Load dictionary entry instead of unpickling a file
def load_file(md5):
    print('loading file with md5 of', md5)
    return storage[md5]
```

I use a custom class as intermediate object:

```
class MemoizedObject(object):
    def __init__(self, md5):
        self.md5 = result_md5

    def get_real_data(self):
        print('load...')
        return load_file(self.md5)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}(md5={self.md5})'.format(self=self)
```

And finally I show the changed `Memoize` assuming your functions take only one argument:

```
class Memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        # The md5 to md5 storage is needed to find the result file 
        # or result md5 for lazy evaluation.
        self.md5_to_md5_storage = {}

    def __call__(self, x, lazy=False):
        # If the argument is a memoized object no need to
        # calculcate the hash, we can just look it up.
        if isinstance(x, MemoizedObject):
            key = x.md5
        else:
            key = calculate_md5(x)

        if lazy and key in self.md5_to_md5_storage:
            # Check if the key is present in the md5 to md5 storage, otherwise
            # we can't be lazy
            return MemoizedObject(self.md5_to_md5_storage[key])
        elif not lazy and key in self.md5_to_md5_storage:
            # Not lazy but we know the result
            result = load_file(self.md5_to_md5_storage[key])
        else:
            # Unknown argument
            result = self.func(x)
            result_md5 = calculate_md5(result)
            create_file(result_md5, result)
            self.md5_to_md5_storage[key] = result_md5
        return result
```

Now if you call your functions and specify lazy at the correct positions you can avoid loading (unpickling) your file:

```
@Memoize
def f(x):
    return x+1

@Memoize
def g(x):
    return x+2
```

Normal (first) run:

```
>>> x1 = 10
>>> y1 = f(x1)
calculating md5 of 10
calculating md5 of 11
creating file for md5 11
>>> y2 = g(y1)
calculating md5 of 11
calculating md5 of 13
creating file for md5 13
```

Without `lazy`:

```
>>> x1 = 10
>>> y1 = f(x1)
calculating md5 of 10
loading file with md5 of 11
>>> y2 = g(y1)
calculating md5 of 11
loading file with md5 of 13
```

With `lazy=True`

```
>>> x1 = 10
>>> y1 = f(x1, lazy=True)
calculating md5 of 10
>>> y2 = g(y1)
loading file with md5 of 13
```

The last option only calculates the "md5" of the first argument and loads the file of the end-result. That should be exactly what you wanted.